# Rearranging labels in screen to avoid overlapping

Tags: labeling, c++, icon, opengl

I have a map, with some icon over it. Every icon has a label next to it. When icons overlaps, labels are overlapped too. In this case, I want to move labels so they don't overlap anymore, with a line linking them with respective icons. Obviously I know size and position of labels and icon, related to screen coordinates.

Which algorithm should I study in order to implement this (I can't use any GIS library)? I've searched for declutter on Internet (I don't speak English very well), but I've found only ideas for hiding/showing icons, not for label moving.

Comment: Which software are you using?

Comment: No GIS software. I'm creating an application using C++/OpenGL and a proprietary software for visualization (Vegaprime). Infact I'd like to know some generic algorithm instead of some softare command/library.

Comment: Wikipedia has an article titled "Automatic Label Placement" with a few references, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_label_placement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a good paper which has a C++ focus. It seems very detailed, 147 pages.[Automated Label Placement In Theory and Practice](http://www1.pub.informatik.uni-wuerzburg.de/pub/wolff/pub/w-alptp-99.pdf)

Comment: Alexander Wolff was scientific assistent at Uni-Greifswald and is now at Uni-Wuerzburg. He is a very friendly one, try to ask him directly  http://www1.informatik.uni-wuerzburg.de/en/staff/wolff_alexander/